# Spring @Cacheable with no value/key specification on method that takes parameters

Tags: spring

What happens if I annotate with a simple Spring `@Cacheable` (no value/key) a DAO method which takes multiple parameters?

DAO Method:

```
@Cacheable("main") // No other specs
public Integer getDBValue(Integer param1, String param2, String param3) {
     //...
}
```

How will Spring perform caching in this case? Suppose the DAO method is invoked with

```
2, "abc", "xyz";
10, "", "some string";
12, "abc", "some string 2";
```

Am I correct that on every call to `getDBValue()`, Spring will maintain a Map called `main` with various combinations of these params (in this case 3 Map entries), and return the cached result that it finds for the single specific combination only (otherwise execute and add the new combination to the Map)?

Comment: The cache key, by default, is determined based on all parameters of the method (this is also in the regular documentation).

Comment: Spring doesn't maintain a Map called `main`.  That is delegated to the cache provider.  The `@Cacheable` annotation creates an `AroundAdvice` on the method that intercepts all calls to it that are across proxy boundaries.  The advice uses the CacheManager to look up the `main` cache by a key that's produced off of the method parameters.  If there's a match, it returns it.  If there's no match, it completes the execution of the method, saves it in the cache, and returns the result.

Comment: The reference doc is at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html